# Would a multiple regression controlling for one variable increase the validity of my study?

Tags: regression, logistic, multiple-regression, predictive-models, multivariate-analysis

I have a study in which the problem is a very low power (low amount of people in the outcome variable). I found during a previous question I asked that we should probably not use multiple regression to report the results of this study.

As we have done a lot of work, we decided to instead report association results with Chi2 and ttests.

My question is, there are 80% women in the study and we actually have a large amount of observations but only 4% in the outcome....Would it increase the validity of our study to take the variables presenting with a low alpha and run a multiple regression on them and gender, to control for gender impact on these association findings? Or would this just muddy the water?

Thank you.